# Unable to add foreign key in associate table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am creating a database and adding tables into it. I am building a associative table but I am not able to add foreign key into it. I am not getting why it is not letting me to do it.

```
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hospital_Management_System`.`Bill_Item` (
      `billId` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      `itemNumber` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
      INDEX `billId_idx` (`billId` ASC)  COMMENT '',
      INDEX `itemNumber_idx` (`itemNumber` ASC)  COMMENT '',
      CONSTRAINT `billId`
        FOREIGN KEY (`billId`)
        REFERENCES `Hospital_Management_System`.`Patient_Bill` (`billId`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `itemNumber`
        FOREIGN KEY (`itemNumber`)
        REFERENCES `Hospital_Management_System`.`Patient_Bill_Item` (`itemNumber`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

The base table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hospital_Management_System`.`Patient_Bill` (
 `patientId` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `billId` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`datebillPaid` DATE NOT NULL COMMENT '',
`amountDue` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`billId`)  COMMENT '',
INDEX `patientIdNumber_idx` (`patientId` ASC)  COMMENT '',
CONSTRAINT `patientId`
FOREIGN KEY (`patientId`)
REFERENCES `Hospital_Management_System`.`Patient` (`patientId`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

and second table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hospital_Management_System`.`Patient_Bill_Item` (
 `itemNumber` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
 `quantity` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `totalAmount` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemNumber`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: your syntax look ok. check your tables are really use innodb engine.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` or `SHOW CREATE TABLE _your_table_`